# CSS custom properties in box-shadow color function render incorrectly in Safari

Tags: css, safari, box-shadow, css-variables

Is this a Safari bug or am I doing something wrong?

Check out this CodePen in Safari vs Chrome and Firefox: https://codepen.io/mattaningram/pen/zWVxzR

Or run code snippet below:

```css
.item {
  --itemColor: 200, 0, 0;
  --itemColorHex: #C80000;
  
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  
  background-color: rgba( var(--itemColor), 1 );
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba( var(--itemColor), .5 );
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba( var(--itemColor), .5 );
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px var(--itemColorHex); THIS WORKS */
  /* color: rgba( var(--itemColor), .5 ); BOX-SHADOW INHERITS THIS PROPERLY IF UNCOMMENTED */
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

In Safari the box-shadow renders as black (it should be red) with no alpha. This does work if you don't use `rgba` (see commented out `box-shadow` line).

Oddly Safari inspect element recognizes the CSS call and is able to identify the CSS custom property value:

[image: Safari Inspect Element]

Even stranger is that if you set the `color` (text color) property of the item to the custom property the box-shadow inherits it and it works (sadly in my actual implementation I need multiple box-shadows so this doesn't fix my issue).

Comment: Hmm...isn't there a *thing* with Safari thinking that transparent values are black instead white? Could that be related?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have got a solution to your problem, if you simply add variable color in box shadow then it won't work in Safari browser. However by doing some manipulation in code, you can do it easily.

Here are few steps to do..

1. Select any root color in RGB value.

   ```
   :root {
        --color: 130, 16, 253;
    }
   ```
2. Add same color but with some opacity to root for **box shadow**. Here is a trick you are using one **variable** in another **--shadowColor** variable.

   ```
   :root {
       --color: 130, 16, 253;
       --shadowColor: 0px 10px 50px 0px rgba(var(--color), 0.08);
   }
   ```
3. Apply color and box shadow to any object.

   ```
   .feature_box
   {   
       color: rgba(var(--color), 1);
       -webkit-box-shadow: var(--shadowColor);
       box-shadow: var(--shadowColor);
   }
   ```

   Enjoy:)

Comment: Wow this worked, sorry I didn't see this earlier! Thanks!

Comment: https://codepen.io/mahendrapatil/pen/MWmvbgY

check this why this is not working

Comment: --color: red; Here red color should be in 0,255,255 format.

Answer (score 8):

It's a Safari bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185940

The only way to make custom properties work in box-shadow, is to put the whole color into variable

```
.item {
  --color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--color);
}
```

Edit: looks like it is fixed since Safari 13.0.3

Answer (score 0):

This may be a "-webkit-box-shadow" type thing.

See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

Comment: Can you clarify? I added `-webkit-box-shadow` line to the snippet and the Codepen has autoprefixer turned on. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Just figured it was a vendor css problem.  I don't have Safari on this computer, so I can't really test it out.  But if the styling works with you putting just numbers instead of the function, it would be Safari just not recognizing the function, I would think.  But then again, according to this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var  it should be.  Huh.  I'm stumped.

Comment: My assumption is it's a Safari bug as well, however it isn't mentioned in the "Known Issues" part of caniuse.com so I thought maybe I was missing something. Any idea how to notify them of the bug?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html would be the place for that, but I would give others some time to answer at least before doing that :)  Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely submit it if no one finds a solution.